# Pick Values From A Oracle Select Query

Tags: linux, sql, oracle-database, sqlplus

I have executed the below command (Part of a 2 step procedure required for password reset when we face the error ORA-28007).

```
SQL> select USER#,NAME,PASSWORD FROM user$ where name='TESTUSER';

     USER# NAME                           PASSWORD
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
        91 TESTUSER                       6D340376A5373473
```

The next step would be to reset the password using the command:-

```
alter user TESTUSER IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '6D340376A5373473';
```

Is there a procedure/script/way to pull the "6D340376A5373473" value into the alter command instead of manually copying and pasting everytime? A solution saves my time dramatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Unix question, and is based on a misunderstanding of how the `alter user` command works.

You don't need to know the old encrypted password if you are `sysdba` or a user with `alter user` privileges.  You just do

```
alter user TESTUSER identified by newpasswd;
```

You may get better answers on future Oracle questions on the dba stackexchange.

Comment: Stephen,You are half right in your own right!

Thing is, It doesn't allow me to edit the user with the same password which i have to fetch from the values from user$ view. In any case, If i have to fetch, IS there a way to automate it?

Comment: I know there are 2 ways that we can do that, But its been a very long time and i forgot them and thats why and how i ended up here. Do help if you could. The purpose is, I will create a SQL and call for the user value which i will link with the user$ and the values should be picked automatically.